# How to view edited page after editing the headers in Fiddler?

Tags: http, sniffing, fiddler

I am playing a bit with Fiddler because it seems to be the tool of choice for HTTP analysis on Windows, but I can't for the life of me understand how to view the new page after I have edited a request header.

I have Fiddler running and I have already edited the headers of an HTTP request, so how do I see the results of the edit in a browser now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have crafted a request in the Composer tab, you should be able to hit the <kbd>Execute</kbd> button and send the request, which should appear as a new entry in the left-hand panel.

Click the new request, and go to the Inspectors tab; at the bottom of this is the response, which you can view in a number of ways by picking from the buttons -- I expect the <kbd>WebView</kbd> button will show you what you want to see...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, marked as accepted because at least now it works :D However, do you know if I can pass the edited response to Firefox to view the page with it?

Comment: Not that I know of.  Apart from *File -> Save -> Response -> Response Body* to your Desktop, with a `.html` extension, then opening that file...